# Htaccess to use the hosting for live testing

Tags: security, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I would use the hosting for live testing, but I want to protect access and prevent search engine indexing.
For example (server directory structure) within public_html:

_private
_bin
_cnf
_log
_ ... (more default directories hosting)
**testpublic**
css
images
**index.html**

I want **index.html is visibile to everyone** and **all other directories (except "testpublic") are hidden, protected access and search engines not to index.**

The directory "testpublic" I wish it was public but may not be indexed in search engines, not sure if this is possible.

To do understand that I need 2 files .htaccess.
One general in "public_html" and other specific for "testpublic".

The .htaccess general (public_html) I think it should be something like:

AuthUserFile /home/folder../.htpasswd
AuthName "test!"
AuthType Basic
require user admin123

< FilesMatch "index.html">
Satisfy Any
< / FilesMatch>

Can anyone help me create the files with the appropriate properties? Thank you!

Comment: For the non-indexing by search engines then a robots.txt should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a robots.txt file in your root folder. All standards-abiding robots will obey this file and not index your files and folders.

Example Robots.txt that tells all (*) crawlers to move on and index nothing.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

You could use .htaccess files to fine tune what your server (assuming Apache) serves out and what directory indexes are visible. In which case you would add

```
IndexIgnore *
```

To your .htaccess file to disallow indexes.

Updated (Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714715/samuel-cook):

If you want to specifically stop a bot/crawler and know its USER AGENT string you can do so in your `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot
  RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you has been a great help!